# Cannot run airflow locally, receiving various errors (InvalidToken, admin already exists, webserver already running)

Tags: python, docker-compose, airflow

I am struggling to run locally our airflow deployment. Here are the logs we are currently receiving:

```
webserver_1  |   ____________       _____________
webserver_1  |  ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
webserver_1  | ____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
webserver_1  | ___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
webserver_1  |  _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:43,668] {dagbag.py:496} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:44,099] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_create Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:44,115] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_edit Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:44,126] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_delete Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:44,461] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists DAG Runs.clear Admin
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
webserver_1  |     sys.exit(main())
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
webserver_1  |     args.func(args)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 91, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/webserver_command.py", line 368, in webserver
webserver_1  |     check_if_pidfile_process_is_running(pid_file=pid_file, process_name="webserver")
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 267, in check_if_pidfile_process_is_running
webserver_1  |     raise AirflowException(f"The {process_name} is already running under PID {pid}.")
webserver_1  | airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The webserver is already running under PID 330.
postgres_1   | LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
cbb-airflow_webserver_1 exited with code 1
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-core==1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-datastore==1.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.15.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: gcsfs==0.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.6.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: flatten-dict in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.4.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: bigquery_schema_generator in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.4)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: backoff in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.11.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: six==1.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.13.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: ndjson in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 8)) (0.3.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 10)) (3.12.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy==1.3.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.3.15)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pandas==1.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 15)) (1.3.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 16)) (1.21.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: billiard in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /requirements.txt (line 17)) (3.6.4.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.31.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: fsspec>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (2021.7.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.4.5)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (5.0.9)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.26.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: google-auth>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.35.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==1.3.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 15)) (2021.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==1.3.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 15)) (2.8.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flatten-dict->-r /requirements.txt (line 4)) (4.6.4)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.17.3)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (57.4.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.53.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (21.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0dev,>=1.29.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.39.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.2->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (4.7.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.2->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (4.2.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.2->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.2.8)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging>=14.3->google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-cloud-core==1.4.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.4.7)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth>=1.2->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.4.8)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.4)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (2021.5.30)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (3.2)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.26.6)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.3.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib->gcsfs==0.6.1->-r /requirements.txt (line 3)) (3.1.1)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->flatten-dict->-r /requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.10.0.0)
webserver_1  | Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->flatten-dict->-r /requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.5.0)
postgres_1   | LOG:  incomplete startup packet
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The hide_sensitive_variable_fields option in [admin] has been moved to the hide_sensitive_var_conn_fields option in [core] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | DB: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres:5432/airflow
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:30:59,666] {db.py:702} INFO - Creating tables
webserver_1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
webserver_1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
webserver_1  |     sys.exit(main())
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
webserver_1  |     args.func(args)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 31, in initdb
webserver_1  |     db.initdb()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 576, in initdb
webserver_1  |     create_default_connections()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 335, in create_default_connections
webserver_1  |     session,
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 61, in merge_conn
webserver_1  |     if not session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == conn.conn_id).first():
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3298, in first
webserver_1  |     ret = list(self[0:1])
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3076, in __getitem__
webserver_1  |     return list(res)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 101, in instances
webserver_1  |     cursor.close()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
webserver_1  |     exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
webserver_1  |     raise exception
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 81, in instances
webserver_1  |     rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 81, in <listcomp>
webserver_1  |     rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 599, in _instance
webserver_1  |     state.manager.dispatch.load(state, context)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 322, in __call__
webserver_1  |     fn(*args, **kw)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3353, in _event_on_load
webserver_1  |     instrumenting_mapper._reconstructor(state.obj())
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 150, in on_db_load
webserver_1  |     if self.password:
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 356, in __get__
webserver_1  |     retval = self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 235, in get_password
webserver_1  |     return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._password, 'utf-8')).decode()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 194, in decrypt
webserver_1  |     raise InvalidToken
webserver_1  | cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The hide_sensitive_variable_fields option in [admin] has been moved to the hide_sensitive_var_conn_fields option in [core] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:31:05,551] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_create Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:31:05,561] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_edit Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:31:05,571] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists View Menus.can_delete Admin
webserver_1  | [2021-10-11 17:31:05,808] {manager.py:573} WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists DAG Runs.clear Admin
webserver_1  | admin already exist in the db
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The hide_sensitive_variable_fields option in [admin] has been moved to the hide_sensitive_var_conn_fields option in [core] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The hide_sensitive_variable_fields option in [admin] has been moved to the hide_sensitive_var_conn_fields option in [core] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
webserver_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:345 DeprecationWarning: The default_queue option in [celery] has been moved to the default_queue option in [operators] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
```

I assume the problematic lines are:

- airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The webserver is already running under PID 330.
- raise InvalidToken, cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
- admin already exist in the db
- cbb-airflow_webserver_1 exited with code 1
- cbb-airflow_webserver_1 exited with code 137 (not showing above but we receive this as well in other current logs)

I am fairly lost as to what has caused these issues. Airflow was working locally just fine, and it stopped working immediately after I had triggered a DAG to run locally. When I visit localhost:8082, localhost:8082/home, localhost:8082/admin, none work, all showing the standard "The site can't be reached" error page.

[image]

Any thoughts on why this might be the case, and how we can resolve this? I can share our `docker-compose.yml` file if this will help. If it helps to know, we also recently updated from Airflow v1 to v2, although Airflow was working previously on v2 before triggering the DAG caused everything to break.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are running both Airlfow 1 and Airflow 2 at the same time. You should make sure you clean-up your environment and only use one airflow version/docker-compose at a time.

You can use the usual docker and docker-compose commands to kill/stop running docker containers. You can easily find the right commands. For example

`docker kill $(docker ps -q)`

Will kill all docker containers.